# PHP Preg_replace doesn't match with french punctuation/accent

Tags: php, regex

I don't understand why this regex doesn't work with french accent/punctuation.

```
 <?PHP
$search=array( '/\bfr\b/', '/\bs.a./', '/\bs.a.r.l./');
$replace=array('');
$nom="fr caissefr federale de credit s.A. mutuel 4 rue frédéric-guillaume raiffeisen 67000 frstrasbourg fr ";
$nom=strtolower($nom);
$nom=preg_replace($search, $replace, $nom);
echo $nom;
?>
```

This regex return
**" caissefr federale de credit  mutuel 4 rue édéric-guillaume raiffeisen 67000 frstrasbourg"**

I want to delete all the "fr" that are alone (or all the acronyms that I can list as "s.a.r.l.") but the regex also removes me the fr in "FRÉDÉRIC" but not the fr de "frstrasbourg" and i dont understand why ??

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please do not use a real address in your example. You can replace it with any string containing accent (or multi-bytes char).

Comment: @AnthonyB how do you know that given address is real not fake?

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde The address in Google Maps matches to a real one. Since this example does not require to have a real address it might be good to use other words to avoid using a real address.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

- Use `u` modifier to make `\b` fully Unicode aware
- Escape all dots that are literal dots

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/3FfD9):

```
$search=array( '/\bfr\b/u', '/\bs\.a\./u', '/\bs\.a\.r\.l\./u');
$replace=array('');
$nom="fr caissefr federale de credit s.A. mutuel 4 rue frédéric-guillaume raiffeisen 67000 frstrasbourg fr ";
$nom=strtolower($nom);
$nom=preg_replace($search, $replace, $nom);
echo $nom;
// => caissefr federale de credit  mutuel 4 rue frédéric-guillaume raiffeisen 67000 frstrasbourg
```

Note that you can test your regex [online](https://regex101.com/) before using them in your code, to debug them. E.g. the version without `u` modifier [matches `Frederic`](https://regex101.com/r/Ostduv/1) while the version with `u` [does not](https://regex101.com/r/Ostduv/2). Here is the list of [available modifiers](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) in PHP.